# Firebase Custom Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I´m new to Firebase and I have been trying to view multiple items in my custom list view.
However, when I use the `android.R.layout` the maximum I´m able to view is a two list item.

Below are my code:

```
qmAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<QMembers>(this, QMembers.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, qmRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View qView, QMembers qMembers, int position) {
                ((TextView)qView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(qMembers.getFullname());
                ((TextView)qView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(qMembers.getTelephone())          }
        };

        qmListView.setAdapter(qmAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Then you should create your custom `ViewHolder`. If you don't know what I'm talking about, perhaps it's better to learn something about `RecyclerView` because it is similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `android.R.layout.two_line_list_item`, which is one of the default item views that is built into Android. There is nothing built-in that has more than two items, so you'll have to build your own item view and wire that up. See this question for some examples of creating such views: [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)